# Is there a way to find the Id of post to be created

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

When I create posts I create slugs for them too, but slugs somehow might be same with another one, eve tho the title is unique. for example if the title is
 `new title` than somebody can create `new-title` which is actually different but when the space is turnet into dash than they are same. In this case I want to add its id to it, here is what I try:

```
$articleslug = new Slugify();
$slug = $articleslug->slugify($request['title']);    

$atyicles = Article::where('slug', $slug)->exists();

if ($atyicles) {
         $lastId = Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
         $getId = $lastId->id + 1;
         $slug = $slug.$getId;
}
$article->slug = $slug;
```

but If a post is deleted before this one created than the id is not gonna be correct. So is there a way to know the id that is gonna be given to the post to be created?

Comment: use something like this: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable that generates slugs for you using a field and will always be unique

Comment: You could just use the `id` of the post as a parameter in a route, not in the slug itself

Comment: Better is first Insert and then Update to make work for sure.

Comment: @kerbholz I know I can do that. but I will use slug for saving articels and other stuff. so it's not just a slug, its almost like secondary id, even better than that. There are not just articels in the application, when I save I get the type and the slug, than generate the url depending on that.

Comment: @C2486 SO you are saying I should update than ckeck if the newly created slug is unique or not, than update it if it's not right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [model event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events) as follow in your `Article` model

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function (Article $article) {
        $articleBySlug = Article::where('slug', $article->slug)->exists();

        if ($articleBySlug) {
            $article->slug = $article->slug.'-'.$article->id;
            $article->save();
        }
    });
}
```

SO that after creating a new article, you check if the slug has already been used and then append the `id` of the article to the `slug` to make it unique.

Comment: Hmm that makes sence